# In Angular2, how can I hide a component based on an event received in that component?

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
<my-component (show)="$event"></my-component>
```

The `$event` property is a boolean which I want to use to hide/show this component.

Is it possible to not render `<my-component>` **without writing new code in the class**? That is, I would preferably just have the logic in the template and not in the class itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just listen to an event and set the `hidden` property depending on the event:

```
class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('hidden')
  isHidden:boolean = false;

  @HostListener('someevent')
  someEventHandler(event) {
    this.isHidden = event;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an event, you could use a class member in your `MyComponent` and bind to the hidden attribute:

```html
<my-component #cmp [hidden]="cmp?.hidden"></my-component>
```

---

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6leC2w9SYykZXViQVTce?p=preview) for example usage